# async.series functions ... is this the right approch?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Heres the code:

```
var async = require('async');
var GitHubApi = require('github');

var github = new GitHubApi({
   version: '3.0.0'
});

var getUserAvatarWithCallback = function(user, callback) {
   github.search.users({ q: user }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) { callback(err, null); }
      else {
        var avatarUrl = res.items[0].avatar_url;
         callback(null, avatarUrl);
      }
    });
};

    async.series([
       function(callback1) {

         for( var i = 0, length = 3; i < length; i++ ) {
            getUserAvatarWithCallback('samucich', function(err,avatar) {
               if (err) { console.log('Error: ',err) };
               console.log('got url from Git',avatar);
            });
          }
         callback1()
    },
       function(callbackAfterLoop) {

         for( var i = 0, length = 10; i < length; i++ ) {
            console.log('loop ',i);
          }

       callbackAfterLoop()
    },
       function() {
       console.log('Done');
    }
    ]);//async
```

And the output:

```
loop  0
loop  1
loop  2
loop  3
loop  4
loop  5
loop  6
loop  7
loop  8
loop  9
Done
got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3
got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3
got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3
```

If i understand this correctly, Node is putting the calls to the Git api onto it's event stack, and then calling my program back when their done. So this is why, in the output, i see the output from the 2nd and 3rd functions in the async array, before i see the output from the 1st async function...the Git api calls take more time...i get that.

My question is how can I get this to wait for the api calls to Git to complete and return and THEN move on to the 2nd function in the async array? is async.series the wrong approch?

Thanks muchly...Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tested out the package and your code and hopefully this is helpful now:

It appears async.series runs each function in a series waiting on a specific callback telling it when to move to the next function in line.

However, if you run a loop with an async function inside of this series, you need to let the series know when all of the async functions of complete.

add a condition that fires the callback when met. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem like a very flexible method since you'll need to know the length beforehand.

```
var count = 0;

async.series([
  function(callback1) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      getUserAvatarWithCallback('samucich', function(err,avatar) {
        if (err) { console.log('Error: ',err) };
        console.log('got url from Git',avatar);
        if (count === 2) {
          callback1();
        }
        count++;
      });
    }
  },
  function(callbackAfterLoop) {
    for( var i = 0, length = 10; i < length; i++ ) {
      console.log('loop ',i);
    }
    callbackAfterLoop()
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Done');
  }
]);//async
```

got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3

got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3

got url from Git https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4983338?v=3

loop  0

...

loop  9

Done

Comment: Thanks Dreamlines...so you're saying not to use the async module at all?

Comment: tested. updating answer.

Comment: Probably better to increment the `count` and then AFTER you've incremented the `count`, check its value to see if it is at the terminal value.  The way you're doing it is quite odd and not so easy to follow.  My first question when reading your code was why are you checking to see if `count` is `2` instead of `3`.  Well, the answer is because you haven't yet incremented the counter.  That's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Seems like personal preference and off topic in general. The question is about running a looped async function nested in a function looking for a callback that tells it to move on. The solution stands that a condition should be added to fire the parent callback. Anything about implementation of that solution isn't really in the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks Dreamlines...this seems to work fine. The good news for my use case is that i will know the number of iterations beforehand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using async.waterfall module to achieve after first callback execute then second should execute.

Comment: A code example would make this a much more useful answer, particularly if you show the OP how to use `async.waterfall()` in the context of their code.